# How to add react.js with typescript in existing Asp.NetCore Webapi project in visual studio

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, webapi

I created a project with Asp.NetCore3.1 and Web API in visual studio 2019 and now I want to add React and TypeScript in there and i don't know how to do that.

I found a few things but they didn't help me.
I can do that with VSCcode and I dont have any problem but I can't do that with Visual Studio. I found that I must put some code in `webapiconfig.cs` but I can't understand what code that is.

`Microsoft Visual Studio 2019` 
`Node 15.4.0`
 `n pm 7.0.15`

Comment: I suggest you could build new project with this [tutorial](https://reactjs.net/tutorials/aspnetcore.html)  This tutorial covers the end-to-end process of creating a brand new ASP.NET MVC website and adding a React component in it. Then compare two project structures and merge into one.

Comment: Ok i read this tutorial and i understand that but i don't know how can i merge into one .can you help me?

Comment: Sorry, I can't do that because I have nothing about your Web API project. You could try by yourself and post the new problem.